# Outlook ribbonbuttons not displaying correctly in Outlook addin

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin

Code first:

**Programmaticaly adding button to a ribbonbar:**

```
for (int i = 0; i < titles.Length; i++)
{
    RibbonButton button = this.Factory.CreateRibbonButton();
    button.Visible = false;
    button.Label = titles[i];
    button.Image = OutlookAddIn1.Properties.Resources.Sans_titre_5;
    button.ControlSize = Microsoft.Office.Core.RibbonControlSize.RibbonControlSizeLarge;
    this.group1.Items.Add(button);
}
```

**Showing/Hiding some buttons programmatically:**

```
private void showOrHide(contact){
    // Building a phone array with the contact infos...
    RibbonButton button = Globals.Ribbons.Ribbon1.ribbonButtons.ElementAt(i).Value;
    button.Visible = button.Enabled = phones[i] != null;
}
```

**I bound an event on all my contactItems.open and it calls this method:**

```
private void Event(ref bool asd)
{
    Outlook.Selection selection = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveExplorer().Selection;
    if (selection.OfType<Outlook.ContactItem>().Count() == 1)
    {
        Outlook.ContactItem contact = selection.OfType<Outlook.ContactItem>().FirstOrDefault();
        showOrHide(contact);
    }
}
```

Has you can see, I am trying to show/hide buttons in my ribbonbar depending on if the contact has a certain phone number type or not.

The first time I open a contact, the ribbonbuttons are correctly shown/hidden:

[image: It works]

But when I select another contact (or the same), it displays all my buttons, without images of labels, even if they are visible=false:

[image: Doesn't work.]

My guess is that outlook breaks my ribbonbuttons when I close my contact window the first time. So when I open another one, the ribbonbuttons are all messsed up.
Anyone has an idea?

Answer (score -1):

Use [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa942955.aspx) method to add ribbon controls to add-ins. It is rather reliable.

Add a ribbon xml from visual studio to your solution and then you can add controls to your ribbon as following.

```
<tab idMso="TabAddIns">  
    <group id="ContentGroup" label="Content">  
        <button id="textButton" label="Insert Text"  
             screentip="Text" onAction="OnTextButton"  
             supertip="Inserts text at the cursor location."/>  
        <button id="tableButton" label="Insert Table"  
             screentip="Table" onAction="OnTableButton"  
             supertip="Inserts a table at the cursor location."/>  
    </group>  
</tab>
```

You can define call backs for events and declare labels and other properties for them at run time. You can invalidate the ribbon controls and control its visibility by declaring a callback method for "getVisible" property of control.